# VBA Run-time error 1004 Method open text of object workbook failed - two scripts in one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on sheet which take files from folder by one button and when I click on one of that files (choose cell with that value) which appears and use second function to open that file in another excel (and do simple change here). This two codes works fine when they are on solo list, but together comes error on Workbooks.opentext.

First part - loading files to list in excel

```
 Dim FSO2 As Object
Dim NalezenoF2 As Long
Dim NalezenoS2 As Long

aktivni = ActiveCell.Value
C1 = Range("C1").Value2
adresa = C1 + aktivni

Set FSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set Start2 = FSO2.getfolder(adresa)
Set subfold2 = Start2.subfolders


 For Each fi In subfold2
  On Error Resume Next
   NalezenoF2 = Range("c:c").Find(what:=fi.Name, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Cells(Cells(65000, 3).End(x1Up).Row + 1, 3) = fi.Name
    End If
   On Error GoTo 0
 Next fi

 For Each si In Start2.Files
  On Error Resume Next
   NalezenoS2 = Range("a:a").Find(what:=si.Name, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
     If Err.Number = 91 Then
       Cells(Cells(65000, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3) = si.Name
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 Next si
```

and second script which open file from marked cell - both script are link to C1 where si adress to files  - C:...

```
   Dim aktivni2 As Variant

  aktivni2 = ActiveCell.Value
  C1B = Range("C1").Value2
  adresa2 = C1B + aktivni2

  ChDir ActiveSheet.Range("c1").Value

  Workbooks.OpenText aktivni2, Origin:= _
    852, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
   Columns(1).Select
   Selection.NumberFormat = "00000000"
   Range("A1").Select
```

Thanks for help